# Changing state with a condition in Redux Slice

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a problem with changing state with condition in Redux Slice.

I have a simple Slice, where I need edit value in state and that's just in case when the payload is same object which is already in the store.

Example of my payload:

```
{
unix: 1667500191,
type: "lunch",
order: 2,
value: "gulash"
}
```

Inputs that have a payload value are actively changed by the administrator.
Therefore, every time I change the input, I capture the values with the help of a reducer and try to check if the given input is already in the store and if so I want to change its value. If it's not in the store, I just want to add it.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = [];

export const menuSlice = createSlice({
  name: "menu",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    add: (state, action) => {
      const { order, type, value } = action.payload;

      let newState = [...state, action.payload];

      newState?.map((item, i) => {
        if (item.type === type && item.order === order) {
          newState[i].value = value;
        }
      });

      return newState;
    },
  },
});

export const { add, remove } = menuSlice.actions;

export default menuSlice.reducer;
```

Can someone please help me? This seems to be broken, but I can't figure out why.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of comparison check is easier if your items have a unique id.  Based on your current code, it seems like an item is a duplicate if it has the same `type` and `order`.  It may help with readability if we move that check into a utility function.

```
const isSameItem = (a, b) => a.order === b.order && a.type === b.type;
```

> Therefore, every time I change the input, I capture the values with the help of a reducer and try to check if the given input is already in the store and if so I want to change its value. If it's not in the store, I just want to add it.

We can make use of the array `.find()` or `.findIndex()` functions to get the existing item.  If there is no existing item then we just `.push()` it to the end of the array.

```
addOrUpdate: (state, action) => {
  // see if it already exists
  const extistingIndex = state.findIndex(item => isSameItem(item, action.payload));
  // add new items  
  if (existingIndex === -1) {
    state.push(action.payload);
  }
  // replace existing items
  else {
    state[existingIndex] = action.payload;
  }
}
```